# Cannot parse string to GUID properly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, guid

I am executing a stored procedure but ended up having an error message:

> Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char.

myGuid is assigned as:

```
myGuid = Guid.Parse(objOrder.orderId.ToString)
```

And I made sure that the value of objOrder.orderId is a valid GUID (with 36 characters). I even tried:

```
Guid.Parse("cc1abb29-9a8d-476a-9046-db417b30d917")
```

And

```
    Try
        myGuid = New Guid(objOrder.orderId.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
```

With no errors.

But whenever I assign `myGuid` a new guid such as:

```
myGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
```

It works fine. So it hasn't to do with my database. I already tried comparing their value/formats(in messageboxes and firebug, as I am using ASP.NET) but the two are same. Why doesn't my stored procedure accept a parsed GUID but do accepts newly generated GUIDs?

This is how I call my stored procedure in VB.NET:

```
    Dim result As String = ""
    result = MicrosoftDB.ExecuteScalar(Of String)(
    "sp_order_save",
    CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    GlobalClass.GetConnectionString(),
    New SqlParameter("orderId", myGuid),
    New SqlParameter("customerId", objOrder.customerId),
    New SqlParameter("employeeId", objOrder.employeeId),
    New SqlParameter("orderDate", Now.Date),
    New SqlParameter("shipName", objOrder.shipName),
    New SqlParameter("shipAddress", objOrder.shipAddress),
    ...
    )
```

And my stored procedure's variables' datatypes:

```
     @orderId uniqueidentifier
    ,@customerId bigint
    ,@employeeId bigint
    ,@orderDate date
    ,@shipName varchar(250)
    ,@shipAddress varchar(250)
    ,@shipCity varchar(50)
    ...
```

Comment: You may want to show the definition of the stored procedure. We are not very good at guessing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the post. Though I still really think it is not my stored procedure's fault.